# Wordpress rotating tweets plugin causes database crash

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We are using the Rotating Tweets plugin with Wordpress. This seems to cause the mysql database to crash/overflow throwing this error:

```
WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query 
UPDATE `wp_options` 
SET `option_value` = 'a:11:{s:13:\"MCHFootball00\";a:2:{s:4:\"json\";a:41:
{i:0;a:23:{s:10:\"created_at\";s:30:\"Thu May 16 14:47:11 +0000
2013\";s:2:\"id\";d:335043759412760576;s:6:\"id_str\";
s:18:\"335043759412760576\";s:4:\"text\";s:140:\"You can 
...
```

The contents of the JSON in this query are some of our tweets (MCHFootball), so it's definitely to do with the rotating twitter plugin.

According to some research, this http://thesocialmediaguide.com.au/2010/07/31/solution-for-wordpress-database-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-for-query/ has a solution for the problem, but the site doesn't exist anymore.

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `SET wait_timeout=600` before the query is executed ? maybe it reaches the timeout value

Comment: I've just tried. No luck.

Comment: what is the error code associated with this error?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the cacheing code.  Each 'call' to the Twitter API is stored in the Wordpress options database.  If you are running a lot of different widgets and shortcodes (or have done so in the past), Rotating Tweets can end up taking up too much storage.

A recent upgrade should have fixed this, but if you are running the latest version and still have a problem, try changing line 758 of the plug-in to:

```
if($numberidentities < 3) return;
```